# Issues and clarification regarding O365 APIs

Tags: azure, office365

I have been working with the O365 APIs and found some weaknesses. I understand we are in preview, I just want to confirm the following, thanks.

There is no expiration information returned with the AuthenticationInfo object. It seems the suggested pattern is to get an AuthenticationInfo object before each call.

The SharePointClient class only supports files, not lists or other resources at this point.

The AuthenticationInfo class cannot be used to secure an entire web application. Instead, each application must authenticate users as appropriate and then use AuthenticationInfo to make subsequent calls to O365.

As an interesting side note, I tried to combine MVC5 "Organizational Accounts" authentication with the AuthenticationInfo class and the application made endless round trips to Azure AD without ever returning a token. Is there some conflict between MVC5 Organizational Account authentication and AuthenticationInfo behavior?

Answer (score 0):

On the `AuthenticationInfo` object expiration - it expires when the refresh token does, which should be a least two weeks. The `AuthenticationInfo.GetAccessToken` delegate implementation keeps track of the issuance time and validity of access tokens and makes sure to refresh them automatically when they are nearing expiration.

Re: `SharePointClient and Lists, etc.`

You are entirely right. This was a scoping decision for this release, but we will be adding support for lists in near future.

There is not supposed to be any conflict between `"Organizational Accounts"` and `AuthenticationInfo`.

I just tried using the combo and it worked fine from project creation (using single organization and read-write access to data) through F5. I had to make sure the project had a unique name because otherwise, the web project was picking up a redirect URL from an old registration. That was unrelated to Office 365 APIs, though.